# Change icon class of Kendo Date Picker Jquery

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am trying to use kendo Jquery Date Picker.

I am referrring https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/datepicker/overview.html for the same.

But instead of default k-i-calendar class I want to use k-i-calendar-date class. But I am not able to change.

Icons: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/icons-web

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/button/configuration/iconclass in this example it talks about changing default icon class.

```
$("#button").kendoButton({
    iconClass: "fa fa-male"
});
```

I tried using the same for my date picker but it doesnot work.

```
kendo.jQuery("#ang_layout1_asof_sdate").kendoDatePicker({
          format: this.inqService.userPref_dateFormat,
          change: this.onChangedatePicker.bind(this),
          value : new Date(this.dateDropDowndefaultItem.DATE_1),
          iconClass: "k-icon k-i-calendar-date"
      });
```

Can anyone help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".k-icon").removeClass("k-i-calendar");
$(".k-icon").addClass('k-i-calendar-date');
```

or

```
$(".k-icon").removeClass("k-i-calendar").addClass('k-i-calendar-date');
```

https://dojo.telerik.com/aViqocOT

Answer (score 1):

The kendoDatePicker widget does not provide an "iconClass" property. You can change the icon after instantiating the widget by calling:

```
$("span.k-i-calendar").removeClass("k-i-calendar-calendar").addClass("k-i-calendar-date");
```